# Is it possible to get the tasks whose status changes in django viewflow?

Tags: django-viewflow

HI is it possible to get the tasks whose status changed on performing a task in django-viewflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can examining `activation.task.leading` chain after calling `activation.done()`